# GWT- DateBox.getTextBox().addValueChangeHandler() not fire event in IE

Tags: java, gwt, textbox, internet-explorer-9, datebox

I tried to used DateBox and add a valueChangeHandler to the DateBox.getTextBox().
It works fine in FF, Chrome, but not IE9. The event is not fired even if the value in the textbox is changed.

I tried to just use TextBox.addValueChangeHandler() in IE9, it works as expected.
So the question is that how I can make the DateBox.getTextBox().addValueChangeHandler() work in IE9.

Can anyone confirm this bug? and any ideas to fix it?

Small piece of code to test:

```
 DateBox dateBox = new DateBox();
 RootLayoutPanel.get().add(dateBox);
 dateBox.getTextBox().addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {
   @Override
   public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
      Window.alert("event fire"); 
  }
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this  :

```
    transactionDate.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<Date>() {
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Date> event) {
        Window.alert(transactionDate.getValue().toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: This is not working on GWT 2.6.1. Event does not fire.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug, it will be fixed in GWT 2.6.

Meanwhile you can use this workaround:

```
dateBox.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<Date>() {
    Date lastDate = null;
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Date> arg0) {
    Date newDate = dateBox.getValue();
    newDate.setHours(0);
    newDate.setMinutes(0);
    newDate.setSeconds(0);

    if (!newDate.equals(lastDate))
    {
        lastDate = newDate;
        doSomething();
    }
}});
```

https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4785